# Is there a way to do automated re-fetching invalidating all cache states for active subscribers at once?

Tags: redux-toolkit, react-admin, rtk-query

Let's say we were to implement a `useRefresh()` hook just like [this one](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v4.1.1/packages/ra-core/src/dataProvider/useRefresh.ts) from `react-admin`. It should invalidate all queries cache states and do automated re-fetching for subscribers. [Similar to `invalidateQueries()` from `react-query`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-invalidation). Is there a way to do that with RTK Query? How could I approach this? I know I could do that for every service api through `dispatch(someApi.util.invalidateTags([...someApiTags]))`. But then I'd need to run that for every api importing all their tags. I was wondering if there's a way to do that globally.

References:

1. https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v4.1.1/packages/ra-core/src/dataProvider/useRefresh.ts
2. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#invalidatetags
3. https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-invalidation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, your application should have almost certainly only one, or maybe two apis, but your formulation of "every single service api" tells me that you somehow went the direction of "a lot of apis". That is almost certainly not how RTK Query is meant to be used.

So my suggestion would be that you consolidate your apis into one - you can keep the endpoint in individual files using the documented [code splitting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting) approaches.

With only one api, you only have to dispatch [resetApiState](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#resetapistate) once.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've gone that direction of having a lot of apis. I have only one base URL. It's an API Gateway that redirects a request to its correspondent service. What I've decided to do was creating an api for every back-end service. Also, I'm indeed using Code Splitting, but not with a single api. I have a single file for every resource. Then these resources endpoints are injected into their service apis. With that I've achieved a sort of mapping of how back-end services are organized in architecture. But as you've said, that's not how RTK is meant to be used.

Comment: My goal was to separate the responsibilities of each service. Since, generally, one service does not interfere with another. With your suggestion, I would then join all endpoints into a single api disregarding this idea of services. But at least I could still keep Code Splitting by resource. I'll definitely consider doing that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: "With only one api, you only have to dispatch resetApiState once." - Does resetApiState trigger refetch like invalidateTags?

Comment: If data is not present, a request will be made for it - so yes, a reset should trigger new requests.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this one? I have a similar issue. I can't use the resetApi because I have other data relying on it.